# How to disable and hide a UITextField

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitextfield

Hi I'm new in iPhone development, how do you disable a UITextField in iPhone development? If it matters, it is a View-Based Application, and the UITextField is named abc.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `[abc setEnabled:NO]` to disallow the user to edit it, or `setHidden` to completely hide it

Answer (score 14):

If you want to hide it completely:

```
abc.hidden = YES;
```

If you just want to prevent user interaction:

```
abc.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

Since UITextField is a subclass of UIView (and UIControl), all the UIView (and UIControl) methods (such as those I used above) are available.

Answer (score 3):

```
[textField setHidden:YES];
[textField setHidden:NO];
```

If it is hidden, the user can't interact with it or see it.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this a few ways.

```
abc.alpha = 0;  //text field is there, just transparent, so it can't be seen.
abc.hidden = TRUE;  // textfield is hidden, not on View at all.

abc.userInteractionEnabled = FALSE;  // user can see the text field and any text
                                     // that has  already been set but cannot edit
```